# jquery sortable from custom event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Implementing an interface for mobile app using jQuery, jQuery-UI and jquery.event.ue.

The sortable widget seems to be hardcoded for items to be sorted on the mousedown/tap event, but I would instead like the sorting to be triggered by the "uheld.uheld" event from jquery.event.ue.

The effect I want from the user's point of view is that a mousedown/tap can scroll the list of items, but a tap-and-hold initiates Sortable's sorting mode.

I've read and Googled quite a bit and haven't found a way to override these embedded event triggers. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know there is no way to override this events in jquery sortable. But If I understand you correctly you should be able to achieve what u want with "Sortable". You can check "Jquery Draggable" too. Maybe it will help you to find o correct solution for your problem.

If you will have still problems maybe provide some code for us. It will help to find a different solution than overriding event triggers.

Comment: Thanks much for the response.  We came to the conclusion that it's not possible to override jquery-ui-sortable event triggers. We ended up eliminating jquery-ui from our project and rolled some custom code for the feature we wanted to use with the sortable module.